# Find value in array and get ID in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, search

I've 2 arrays with different structures (dimension), i need to find values (post_name) of $first in $second and then get ID from $second in order to create a unique array with post_name of $first and corresponding ID founded in $second. i hope i'm clear enough...

I need to keep the same order of first 
 Thanks

```
$first= Array
(
    [0] => 'lundi-5',
    [1] => 'mardi-5',
    [2] => 'lundi-1',
    [3] => 'mardi-1',
    );



$second=Array
(
    [0] => WP_Post Object
        (
            [ID] => 2878

            [post_name] => lundi-1

        )

    [1] => WP_Post Object
        (
            [ID] => 3180
            [post_name] => mardi-1

        )

    [2] => WP_Post Object
        (
            [ID] => 3181
            [post_name] => lundi-5

        )

    [3] => WP_Post Object
        (
            [ID] => 3182

            [post_name] => mardi-5

        )
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try with:

```
$keys = array_map(function ($post) {
  return $post->ID;
}, array_filter($second, function ($post) use ($first) {
  return in_array($post->post_name, $first);
}));
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [2]=>
  int(3181)
  [3]=>
  int(3182)
}
```

To return whole objects, use:

```
$posts = array_filter($second, function ($post) use ($first) {
  return in_array($post->post_name, $first);
});
```

Comment: thanks !!! but sorry i don't understand that array structure...How could i obtain as a result an array like this : 
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] =>lundi-5
            [id] => 3181
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => mardi-5
            [id] => 3182
        )
)

Comment: ahh it seems to work but returned result does not seem to be ordered like $first

Comment: would you have an idea @hsz please ?