# Filtering array from another array

Tags: php, arrays

I 've 2 arrays

- $first that is my model for ordering my result and containing a
  list of days of weeks (it's an example, it changes every week)
- $second that is a list of 35 days on 5 weeks (from Monday-1 to
  Sunday-5) with ID an name

As $result i nedd an array ordered like $first but with data from $second (ID, post_title, post_name)

I can a goot result using :

```
$posts = array_filter($second, function ($post) use ($first) {
  return in_array($post->post_name, $first);
});
```

But the problem $posts is not ordered like $first.

Thanks

```
$FIRST
Array
(
    [0] => Monday-5
    [1] => Tuesday-5
    [2] => Wednsday-5
    [3] => Thursday-1
    [4] => Friday-1
    [5] => Saturday-1
    [6] => Sunday-1
)

$SECOND
 Array
(
    [0] => WP_Post Object
        (
            [ID] => 2878
            [post_title] => Monday-1
            [post_name]  => monday-1
        )

    [1] => WP_Post Object
        (
            ID] => 2879
            [post_title] => Tuesday-5
            [post_name]  => tuesday-5
        )
    ...

    [34] => WP_Post Object
        (
            ID] => 2899
            [post_title] => Sunday-5
            [post_name]  => sunday-5
        )
)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find value in array and get ID in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39250988/find-value-in-array-and-get-id-in-php)

Comment: Not exactly, i've not the result is not well ordered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right you want to have an result array containing first all elements with `[post_title] => Monday-5` then all `[post_title] => Tuesday-5` and so on, right?

Then create a third empty array `$result`. Iterate over the `$first` and inside this Iterate over the `$second` and copy ever item from `$second` into `$result` witch fulfill your condition `$first[$i] == $second[$i]['post_title']`.

```
$result = array();
foreach($first as $scope){
  foreach($second as $id=>$item){
    if($item->post_title == $scope){
      $result[$id] = $item;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: in this case my first element in $result would be [ID] => 2978 [post_title] => Monday-5 [post_name]  => monday-5
I tried you loop but it stops PHP...

Comment: it seems the problem is with $item , is not it ?

Comment: try `if($item->post_title == $scope){` instead of `if($item['post_title'] == $scope){`

Comment: seems to work with strtolower($item->post_title) == $scope

Comment: So what is the output of `echo $first[0]` ?

Comment: ah i understand i've "monday-5" in my server and "Monday-5" here, so no problem you solved my question , THANKSSS !